# Quivers with a binary operation on the arrows

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, category-theory

A set with an arbitrary binary operation is called a *magma*.

A set of dots with a set of arrows between them is called a *quiver*.

A *category* is a quiver with a binary operation on the arrows obeying some conditions.

> Is there a name for quivers with an *arbitrary* binary operation on
>   the arrows (that doesn't have to obey any conditions)?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this concept is meaningful enough to deserve a name?